# Touchpad pointer lags / hangs / jumps

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, screen, cursor, hp-touchpad

I have HP Mini 210 and I tried to install Ubuntu, Xubuntu and even Lubuntu. But the problem is the same: when moving the cursor I see lags between cursor's previous position and current and sometimes the touchpad becomes barely responsive.

I tried to configure xorg files, but it didn't help so I reverted all to normal.

Is there some workaround for that?